# Shortest path for the knight (BFS)

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong with my code. I am trying to get the shortest path using BFS to solve the problem but it's either giving me -1 or 2. It should give me 6 as the answer. What am I doing wrong? This is the problem:

Given a chess board, find the shortest distance(minimum number of steps) taken by a knight to reach given destination from given source.

For example, N = 8 (8 x 8 board), Source = (7, 0) Destination  = (0, 7)

Minimum number of steps required is 6

My code is below:

```
class Point {
    int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
 }
}

class knightShortestPath {
    int N = 8;
    public static boolean visited[][];

public boolean isPositionValid(int x, int y){
    if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > this.N || y > this.N){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void createChessBoard(int N) {
    this.N = N;
    visited = new boolean[this.N][this.N];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.N; j++) {
            visited[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
}

public int BFS(Point source, Point destination) {
    int row[] = {2, 2, -2, -2, 1, 1, -1, -1};
    int col[] = {1, -1, 1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2};
    Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.offer(source);
    visited[source.x][source.y] = true;
    int minimumNumSteps = 0;

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int size = queue.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Point pt = queue.poll();
            if (pt.x == destination.x && pt.y == destination.y) {
                return minimumNumSteps;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                Point next = new Point(pt.x + row[i], pt.y + col[j]);
                if (isPositionValid(pt.x + row[i], pt.y + col[j]) && !visited[i][j]) {
                    visited[i][j] = true;
                    queue.offer(next);
                }
            }
        }
        minimumNumSteps++;
    }
    return minimumNumSteps;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    knightShortestPath position = new knightShortestPath();
    position.createChessBoard(8);
    Point src = new Point(0,7);
    Point dest = new Point(7,0);
    System.out.println("The minimum number of steps are: " + position.BFS(src, dest)); //answer is 6
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: I have no idea how you can end up with a negative value. You never decrease `minimumNumSteps` after initializing it with 0. An overflow possibly? Seems weird to me ..

Besides that, I see two issues:

1. The two for loops are incorrect. You currently iterate over the `queue.size()`. What you want to do instead is iterating over all children of the current node.
2. Poll the current point outside of the for loops.

So:

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Point pt = queue.poll();
    // check if it's target 
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        // ... 
        for (int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Another note: When the queue is empty and you have not reached the goal, there is no solution. Currently, you are returning some value that may be interpreted falsely.